# Leaflet - add WMTS Layer from capabilities document?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'd like to ask method to add WMTS layer from capabilities in Leaflet.

I have a [WMTS link](http://gis.sinica.edu.tw/tgos/wmts) which will response a capabilities document;
however, it seems no native leaflet method to add WMTS layer from the xml document like [OpenLayer](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts-layer-from-capabilities.html).

I've searched methods and found a npm package "[wms-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wms-client)" which can easily parse the WMTS capabilities, but I have no idea how to continue with it to add the WMTS layer from the capabilities in leaflet. Is there any better solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the plugin [leaflet.TileLayer.WMTS](https://github.com/mylen/leaflet.TileLayer.WMTS) to add a WMTS layer to your map.

Look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qgzqmn2s/3/) to see how the WMTS layer can be included.

```
L.TileLayer.WMTS('http://yoururl/wmts', {layer: "thelayername", format: "image/jpeg", style: "default", tilematrixSet: "thetilematrixset",});
```

You might need a key for the WMTS service and it's possible that you have to select another layer (look at your XML document, the layers and the URL are listed there).

Comment: Thank you for reply. Actually, I've tried this plugin but in vain. This service is open and key is not necessary. This is my code for the tile layer.     
`var myWMTSlayer = new L.TileLayer.WMTS('gis.sinica.edu.tw/tgos/wmts';, {layer: "F2IMAGE_W", format: "image/png", style: "default", tilematrixSet: "GoogleMapsCompatible",});`